# Stopping user from ending my Android launcher app using task switcher

Tags: android, android-launcher

is there a way of preventing a user from ending my app using the task switcher? Either by removing my app from the task switcher, or disabling the task switcher altogether? My app is a launcher, and when the user ends the task, it reverts back to the stock launcher, which is not desirable behavior.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this previously asked question:

[how to keep my launcher out of being kill by os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281388/how-to-keep-my-launcher-out-of-being-kill-by-os)

Also some tutorial links, just in case:

[xda: Create your own Android Launcher (Video Series)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2583692)

[Tutsplus: build a custom launcher on android](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY when starting your activity should remove your activity from the tasks - not sure how it'll behave with a launcher.